# Laravel query is looking for column which doesn't exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have function for image upload which during product creation. This is the function in createSubmit in the controller

```
public function productsCreateSubmit()
{

    $product = new Product;
    $product->title = Input::get('title');
    $product->price = Input::get('price');
    if (Input::hasFile('image')) {
        $file = Input::file('image');
        $filename = str_random(20);
        $file->move('uploads/', $filename . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension());
        $imagePath = 'uploads/' . $filename . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image = Image::make($imagePath);

        if ($image->width() > 200) {
            $image->resize(200, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
        }
        if ($image->height() > 200) {
            $image->resize(null, 200, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
        }
        $image->save();
    } else {
        $imagePath = 'default.png';
    }
    $product->image = $imagePath;
    $product->save();
    return Redirect::to('/admin/products');
}
```

When I click on submit I receive the error that column in database doesn't have default value.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'file_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `products` (`title`, `price`, `image`) values (test, 1, uploads/awy3CvVHLajER1E1gfpu.jpg))

The problem is that I don't have such a column in the table. This is the model of product

```
class Product extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';
    public $timestamps = false;        
}
```

How the laravel decide to insert/look for this field?

Comment: Can you add your migration file  for product table

Comment: I don't have migration for this. It was created directly in phpmysql

Comment: Are you sure you don't have this column in database even if you don't use it in the controller?

Comment: I have it but I don't use it anywhere in the save() statement in the controller

Comment: Doesn't matter that you'e not using it, Eloquent is. Put default value for the column and the function will work.

Comment: Please check your fillable array inside model file.

Comment: Can you show full code of your models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `file_id`  column in your database table , goto the structure of table in phpmyadmin then click on `change` in front of file_id column then set attribute `default to NULL` and tick the `Null checkmark`. 
Click on Save !

Re run the project !

Answer (score 0):

This is not about laravel, you have a `file_id` field in your database which doesn't have a default value, probably you have a `files` table too.

While saving laravel is setting only three fields: `title`, `price` and `image` but not `file_id` and since the `file_id` doesn't have a default value mysql doesn't know what to fill it with and returning an error.

You can change `file_id` to nullable and set it's default value to null.